# Custom Avalonia controll to render from other thread performance problem

Tags: c#, wpf, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a background thread, which renders some image to WriteableBitmap.
I'm making a custom control, which will use this writeablebitmap and update every frame to make animation.
Unfortunately, now forcing this control to `InvalidateVisual()`.
That worked, but the performance is pretty bad.
On the main window I subscribed to Renderer.SceneInvalidated to log some framerates.

```
this.Renderer.SceneInvalidated += (s, e) =>
{
    _logs.Add((DateTime.Now - _prev).Ticks);

    _prev = DateTime.Now;
};
```

And found that about 7%-10% frames are rendered in 30ms, and others 90% in 16ms.
So I'm looking for a better performance solution with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize custom drawing operation API with direct access to SKCanvas on the render thread.

```cs
public class CustomSkiaPage : Control
{   
  public CustomSkiaPage()
  { 
    ClipToBounds = true;
  } 
        
  class CustomDrawOp : ICustomDrawOperation
  { 
    public CustomDrawOp(Rect bounds)
    {   
      Bounds = bounds;
    }   
            
    public void Dispose()
    {   
      // No-op in this example
    }   

    public Rect Bounds { get; }
    public bool HitTest(Point p) => false;
    public bool Equals(ICustomDrawOperation other) => false;
    public void Render(IDrawingContextImpl context)
    {   
      var canvas = (context as ISkiaDrawingContextImpl)?.SkCanvas;
      // draw stuff 
    }   
  } 

  public override void Render(DrawingContext context)
  { 
    context.Custom(new CustomDrawOp(new Rect(0, 0, Bounds.Width, Bounds.Height)));
    Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(InvalidateVisual, DispatcherPriority.Background);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Well, that's fine, but I cant find a way to set pixels from my Bitmap/WriteableBitmap on this control. For example I need a method 
public void SetBitmap(WriteableBitmap bmp) {...}

Comment: Since you want maximum possible performance, you currently have to use SKBitmap directly instead of WritableBitmap.